# Display / find started applications in Unityu Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: unity

i am new to Unity and miss the 'feature' that when i start a
program that runs in the background (like Autokey or Wuala), i can
start them from the Dash, but they are nowhere visible...
Not in the applist on the left, not in the topmenubar.

What am i missing here?

Thanks for any help.

Ray

Comment: If found this: and that helps!
http://www.dylanmtaylor.com/2012/03/31/fixing-autokey-gtk-on-ubuntu-12-04/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean like a task manager, [then take a look at this](http://modifyubuntu.com/#speed)

Or [This](http://www.blog.highub.com/linux/ubuntu-equivalent-to-task-manager/)

Comment: That first link is a good one thank you! 
But i think i answered my own question already, see my own comment above ;-)